# How do I log repeated guesses and display a message when guesses are inputted?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a high-low game where a user inputs different guesses into a form. I'm trying to account for user repeated guesses and I want to be able to log the repeated guesses and display a message saying "You already tried that. Guess again." Not too sure how to go about this. The if statement is the best I could come up with but then every guess that I input comes up with that message whether it's a repeat or not.

```js
let valid_input = false;
let number, input;
let totalGuess = [];

while (!valid_input) {
  input = window.prompt("Enter any number greater than zero:");

  number = Number(input);

  if (number != NaN && number > 0) {
    valid_input = true;
  }
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('choice', do_guess)

let num = Math.round(Math.random() * number) + 1;

function do_guess() {
  let guess = Number(document.getElementById("choice").value);

  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  let prev_guess;
  if (prev_guess == guess) {
    message.innerHTML = "You already tried that. Guess again."
  } else if (guess == num) {
    message.innerHTML = `
That is correct!Nice job! < /br> You attempted it a total of ${totalGuess.length+1} times. These were your guesses ${totalGuess}`
    console.log(`Your total attemps were ${totalGuess.length+ 1} guesses.`);
    console.log(totalGuess);
    totalGuess = [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep an array of all the previous guesses and add each guess to it:

```js
guesses = []
```

and add to it in `do_guess`

```js
let guess = Number(document.getElementById("choice").value);
// ...
if (guess in guesses) {
    message.innerHTML = /* ... */;
} else {
    guesses.push(guess)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the majority of code in functions. It was confusing trying to find the logic of the OP interface -- there's a `prompt()` which IMO facilitate bad UX, and then there is evidence of form controls (ex. `<input>`, `<button>`, etc). In the example provided I have put `prompt()` out of it's misery. Also, there was no max value for the mystery number so I set the cap to 100. The example also has a test `<input>` that displays the mystery number (for demo only).

**Example will:**

- Accept a real number between 1 to 100.
- Provide a mystery number for the user to guess.
- Compares user guess vs X and inform the user if it matched, already guessed that.
  particular number, or failed to match.
- Build an array that contains all unique numbers that the user guessed.
- Display the unique number array in a `<ul>`.

**Note:** I didn't add a behavior once the number was successfully matched -- I'll leave that to you. If you need help start another question and reference this question.

***Details are commented in example***

```js
/* Declare variables that you don't want to be overwritten 
outside of function
*/
let tries = [];
// Utility function returns an array of unique values.
/* Just realized that this function isn't really needed 
since there's a check for dupes 
*/
const uniques = tries => [...new Set(tries)];
// Generate a number 1 to 100
let X = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
/* Bind the event handler: guessInt(e) to the button. It will
listen for the click event, there's no such thing as an event 
called choice
*/
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', guessInt);

// Pass the Event Object
function guessInt(e) {
  const message = document.querySelector(".message");
  const log = document.querySelector('.log');
  // Get the value user entered and turn into an interger
  let guess = parseInt(document.getElementById("choice").value);
  /* if guess is NOT a NaN AND guess is greater than 0 and 
  less than 101...
  */
  if (!Number.isNaN(guess) && guess > 0 && guess < 101) {
    // if guess matches a number in tries...
    if (tries.includes(guess)) {
      /* Inform the player current guess has already  
      been used.
      */
      message.innerHTML = `${guess} was already picked, try again.`;
    // If guess actually matches X...
    } else if (guess === X) {
      // Add guess to tries...
      tries.push(guess);
      // Run tries through uniques() to remove any dupes
      tries = uniques(tries);
      // Inform user that guess matched in N tries.
      message.textContent = `${guess} is correct! It took a total of ${tries.length} guesses:`;
      // Log the match to list
      tries.forEach(num => log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<li>${num}</li>`));
    } else {
      // Otherwise inform user that there was no match.
      message.innerHTML = `${guess} is incorrect, try again.`;
    }
      // Add guess to tries...
      tries.push(guess);
      // Run tries through uniques() to remove any dupes
    tries = uniques(tries);
    // Reset log
    log.replaceChildren();
    tries.forEach(num => log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<li>${num}</li>`));
  }
/* ↘️ For Demo Only ↙️ */
  const secret = document.querySelector('#secret');
  secret.value = X;
  secret.type = 'text';
/* ↗️ For Demo Only ↖️ */
};
```

```html
<label for='guess'>Pick an integer between 1 and 100</label><br>
<input id='choice' type='number' min='1' style='display: inline-block;width: 5ch;'><button class='btn'>GO</button>

<!-- ↘️ For Demo Only ↙️ -->
<input id='secret' type='hidden' readonly style='display: inline-block;width: 3ch;color: red;'><label for='secret'> Test secret</label><br>
<!-- ↗️ For Demo Only ↖️ -->

<section class='message'></section>
<ol class='log'></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need prev_guess to be a hashmap or an array, so you can store all of the previous tries:

```
let prev_guess = {};
...
if (prev_guess[guess]) {
    // Already tried
} else {
    prev_guess[guess] = true;
    // Test whether it's correct or not
}
```